# What is Tony Stark's PhD field subject?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

In the *Iron Man*, is it said at the beginning of the film that Tony Stark has a PhD in Physics. Is it ever mentioned more precisely in what field he had this PhD?
Is it related with JARVIS or his Iron Man suit?

Comment: JARVIS is just a computer/AI and the Iron Man suit didn't exist at the beginning of the movie, so I'm not sure what his PhD in physics would have to do with either of them.

Comment: His knowledge in physics doesn't even come up in any of the Iron Man movies AFAIK, but he does bring up thermonuclear astrophysics in the Avengers.

Comment: @Monty129 He does make a tiny, self-contained fuel cell capable of outputting several barrelfuls of gasoline worth of energy, and manages to hammer together a brand new, stable, synthetic element in a home-built particle accelerator. That's gotta take at least a little bit of physics know-how >_>

Comment: His exploits and feats point more to an engineering degree rather than a science degree. However some of the theoretical work in the second movie do point to the latter. It's possible he has dual PhDs, it's not unknown.

Comment: He really didn't invent the ARC reactor, nor did he discover Vibranium in the second movie, his father (with some assistance from Igor Vanko) created the ARC he just miniaturized it (which would take some extensive knowledge in physics but not necesarilly doctorate level) He engineers a miniature version wich is more of an engineering feat.

Comment: I would argue that it most certainly would require a doctorate level understanding of physics (and much, much more) to synthesize a new, stable element, even if someone else told him how many protons to use :). Miniaturizing the ARC reactor, I'll give you that. That may very well be in the realm of super-engineering :)

Comment: JARVIS and his father did all the leg work for him in synthesizing Vibranium @jono He's always been depicted as an engineer in the comics (that's even what he describes himself as "I engineer the future")

Comment: It's simple.  He has a degree in 'SCIENCE!', the field that covers any technical knowledge in comic-related media (except that which the plot requires it doesn't).

Comment: @JohnO: I know plenty of physics graduates who are extremely well versed in engineering. The two fields are not mutually exclusive and someone interested in one is often interested in the other. Most people on this page seem to be assuming that someone with a PhD in <X> can only do <X>-related activities for the rest of their lives.

Comment: Tony has multiple doctorates, apparently; https://comicnewbies.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/doctors.jpg?w=768&h=647

Comment: "Analysis of topological inconsistencies to enhance efficient cheese fridge stocking".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IIRC, in the movie they mention he went to MIT (in the magazine/newspaper montage?) but nothing beyond that

Is his degree related directly to his inventions? I don't think so. In the movie the MIT story had him next to a robot; but they didn't specifically say Robotics engineer or AI engineer. His degree seems to be more "general"

In the comics: he was a boy genius, went to MIT at age 15 and had masters degrees in electrical engineering and physics. Nothing specific beyond that

Answer (score 9):

In comic book canon, I have seen a reprinted and posted page where Stark is in a private meeting with Captain America, Dr. Reed Richards, Dr. Stephen Strange and Professor Xavier.

Drs. Richards and Strange address each other with honorifics. Stark then points out that he has **three doctorates**. There's no discussion of the fields in which he studied though.

[image]
<sub><sup>**[New Avengers Vol 2 #29](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/New_Avengers_Vol_2_29)**</sup></sub>

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the comic panel you're referring to. It's from *New Avengers Vol 2 #29*

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering where that came from.

Comment: Whilst this is indeed a nice answer it is worth noting that this question is scoped to the MCU canon.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - OP did stress that in his opening statement. I think it's still worthy of mention.

Comment: @Valorum Me too and I have upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:** We don't know *for certain* exactly what field he studied in at MIT. However, we know he has a degree from MIT where he graduated summa cum laude. He won the Robot Design Award four years in a row though so he potentially studied in Robotics but it doesn't necessarily have to be the case.

I will note though that I don't know where the information on him having a PhD or studying physics comes from, I can't find much to back that up.

---

According to the SHIELD case files supplied with *The Avengers* DVD release we know the following, note it doesn't say he has a PhD.

> Education:
>
> Phillips Academy, Andover, MA
> 1977 - 1984
>
> BS, Engineering Massachusetts Institute of Technology    Cambridge, MA
> 1984 - 1987

[image: The case file, relevant section quoted above]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

In the film itself we only know he graduated *"summa cum laude from MIT"* but not what in from the presentation overview:

> **Voice over:** Tony Stark. Visionary. Genius. American patriot. Even from an early age, the son of legendary weapons developer Howard Stark quickly stole the spotlight with his brilliant and unique mind. At age four, he built his first circuit board. At age six, his first engine. And at 17, he graduated summa cum laude from MIT.
>
> <sub>*Iron Man*</sub>

It is worth noting that during the presentation we do see a few articles and images shown. One of them is a cover for Technology Review with the title *"Tony Stark MIT's Robotic Wunderkind"*. So it is certainly possible that his degree was in robotics. We also see an article on Tony where it is quoted that he has been working in the field of "Advanced Robotics" which would again support this. The article is quite repetitive but there is some interesting information in it.

[image: Technology Review cover] [image: Article on Tony, relevant sections quoted below]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

> **In a dark corner of the Advanced Robotics Laboratory in the basement of Hornberg, wunderkind Tony Stark has been quietly doing groundbreaking work in the field of Advanced Robotics.** Although he is only 16, the MIT junior is doing work that is leaving seasoned professors scratching their heads. Stark, going off of a radically simple theorem that artificial intelligence can be imbibed with personality through alternative programming, is currently putthing the finishing touches on two robotic prototypes that he believes will listen to him and learn from his behaviours.
>
> [...]
>
> "It's a lot of fun to create something new", says Stark. **This month he has won the fourth annual MIT Robot Design Award.** "I really wanted to win this one. So I did", says Stark.
>
> [...]
> This year will mark the fourth consecutive year in a row that Tony has won the MIT Robot Design Award and each year his creations have become more complex;

Answer (score 0):

He has PhD's in physics and electrical engineering as mentioned in the Marvel Comics home page. There is no mention of any other field if he has attended, but given that he is the head engineer of his company, I would assume he gained expertise as he grew.
https://www.marvel.com/characters/iron-man-tony-stark/in-comics

As for tony stark in the movies, he does not have any PhD's as shown in the deleted scene of shield files

Comment: The most relevant part of this answer (and the part that isn't repeating information in the other answers) is about the deleted scene. Could you [edit] this to expand on it more? What deleted scene? Do you have a screen shot or video clip? That would really help this answer out.